# Invoke-Expression, Verbatim Strings, and Invoking Scripts From Other Scripts in PS

Tags: c#, powershell

I am attempting to call a ps1 script from another ps1 script. These scripts all exist in the same directory. I am able to get a string representing the current directory using the following:

```
$ScriptDir = Split-Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path -Parent
```

This works, no problem. To call the secondary script, I am using the Invoke-Expression command, using the above **$ScriptDir** path and hardcoding the script name (this can be seen at the bottom of this post). However, every time I do this it does a path complaint similar to:

```
C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual : The term 'C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or 
operable program.
```

Normally, in C# this is no problem for me to solve, it is a verbatim string issue. However, I do not see a way to make this work in powershell. For reference, here is a slimmed down version of the completed code I am using to test:

```
ScriptDir = Split-Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path -Parent
Write-Host "InvocationName:" $MyInvocation.InvocationName
Write-Host "Path:" $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
write-host "Starting Test..."
Invoke-Expression "$ScriptDir + \Foo.ps1"
```

I know I am missing something small.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
Invoke-Expression "$ScriptDir + \Foo.ps1"
```

It should be:

```
& "$ScriptDir\Foo.ps1"
```

Comment: I tried all of them in ISE, and they all resulted in "The term 'C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or 
operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again."

Comment: Removed the others, Invoke-expression ends up requiring double-escapes since powershell parses the string first, then Invoke-Expression gets the post-processed string.

Comment: Invoke-expression is nearly always the wrong approach to a problem.